# -5V to 5V Range rescaled to +5V - 0V - +5V

Tags: motor-controller

I'm looking to take two signals being generated by a PLC (dual 4-20 mA signals) and convert them into a controllable voltage for a fan controller.

I now have a -5 V to 5 V input available via the subtractor seen below, but I would like to adjust it so that:

- -5 V is converted to 5 V and is a full pull
- 0 V is off
- 5 V is also 5 V for a full push

For clarification, "full push" and "full pull" are in reference to an H-Bridge driving the fans i.e. the fan direction being reversed.

These can't be logic levels as they're analog control voltages. Is there a way to do this or should I reconsider how I'm taking in these signals?

[image: -5V to 5V subtractor]

Comment: What do "full pull" and "full push" mean?

Comment: You want a single output that swings from +5->0->+5 with a single input of -5->+5?  If so an absolute value circuit might do it for you.

Comment: Do you mean a differential pair output? Please edit your question and explain all the full push, full pull, stuff. I don't think anyone recognises these terms in that way. Thanks.

Comment: @kieran please ask a specific question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you wish

$$V_{out} = \text{ABS}( V_{in})$$

This is easily accomplished with an absolute value circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN3Txs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

If I have misunderstood your requirements, or I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you Math. For clarification, "full push" and "full pull" were in reference to an H-Bridge driving the fans ie. the fan direction being reversed. Thank you all.

Comment: @KieranClifford, posting this info everyone was asking for down here is of no real use. Instead, please can you edit your question and edit this information into it as a clear explanation.